# JSF Page to backing bean absurd latency

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, jsf, primefaces

In the system I'm working on, we have a page whose backing bean implements an API to fetch data from a database other than the system's main (user-related) one, and stores the data locally (in memory).

Part of the object that is stored is a link (and a Javascript function) that points to the secondary system's related page.

Here's my relevant code from the JSF page;

```
<p:dataTable id="dtDemonstrativoBoletos" value="#{bean.boletos}" rowKey="#{boleto.link}"
widgetVar="dtDemonstrativoBoletos" var="boleto" 
selection="#{bean.boletoSelecionados}" rowIndexVar="#{boleto.link}">
    <p:autoUpdate />
    <p:column selectionMode="multiple" width="0" toggleable="false"/>
    <!-- columns -->
    <p:column width="24" style="padding-left:0;">
        <p:link href="#{boleto.link}" target="_blank" >
            <i class="fa fa-eye" style="color:darkslategrey;"/>
        </p:link> 
    </p:column>
    <p:ajax event="rowDblselect" listener="#{bean.redirecionarBoleto} update="dtDemonstrativoBoletos"/>
</p:dataTable>
```

Backing bean method;

```
public void redirecionarBoleto() throws IOException {
    try {
        if (!this.boletoSelecionados.isEmpty()) {
            PrimeFaces.current().executeScript(this.boletoSelecionados.get(0).getLinkJs());
        } else if (this.boletoSelecionado != null) {
            PrimeFaces.current().executeScript(this.boletoSelecionado.getLinkJs());
        }
        this.getBoletoSelecionado().redirecionarJavascript();
        /* the getBoletoSelecionado() method returns either the this.boletoSelecionado object
        or attributes the first element in the this.boletoSelecionados list to it, 
        just to be clear */ 
        this.boletoSelecionados = new ArrayList<Boleto>();
    } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
}
```

and object class.

```
public class Boleto {
    private String situacao;
    private String descricao;
    private String codigoBoleto;
    private String codigoEntidade;
    private String link;
    private String linkJs;
    private Date dataVencimento;
/*getters and setters*/ 
    public void redirecionarJavascript() {
        PrimeFaces.current().executeScript(this.linkJs);
    }
}
```

The API sets the `link` property as a parametrized .xhtml with the `codigoBoleto` and `codigoEntidade` values and the `linkJs` property with `boleto.setLinkJs("window.open('" + boleto.getLink() + "')");`.

Now into the issue: since the link is readily available on the `DataTable`, clicking on it redirects correctly to the page (as expected) within 1.12 and 1.48 seconds (going from localhost to production server), while the ajax event takes up to 50 seconds to *reach the backing bean*. I'm not even joking. Once it gets to the bean, it takes nil time to process the actual method (longest delay is between me seeing that it reached the breakpoint and pressing 'Skip') and the same amount of time - a second and a half - to reach the other page.

Any suggestions as to why my page straight up doesn't want to reach the code will be very warmly welcomed. Also, the `linkJs` property was implemented as a testing measure, to be immediately called, but the ajax can't see the `boleto` variable in the `DataTable` - I get a `PropertyNotFoundException` or some such. Also, I need it to work with `rowDblselect` due to system standardization.

Comment: Try removing `<p:autoUpdate />` that should never be on a DataTable...

Answer (score -1):

Regarding the "PropertyNotFoundException" issue. It may be because the getter and setter methods are missing for that specific property or because you have not created the JSF 2.3 configuration class in the package where you have the backing bean.

```
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.faces.annotation.FacesConfig;
import static javax.faces.annotation.FacesConfig.Version.JSF_2_3;

@FacesConfig(version=JSF_2_3)
@ApplicationScoped
public class ConfigurationJSF {

}
```

That is the configuration for JSF 2.3

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).